# If I make a mob farm on a another mob farm would that increase the spawning rates or would it not matter?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So I have a mob farm (the regular one) and it works pretty fine. I was thinking that if I make another one on top of it would that increase the loot I get?
[image: Regular Mob Spawnner]

Comment: It's common practice to do that, but there's also a limit to how far away and how much spawns happen. If you worry about rates and efficiency, build a better farm design instead of more of the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this particular farm design, more layers do help efficiency, since it creates more areas for the mobs to spawn. Mobs spawn within 24-32 blocks away from the player, and outside of that range, they won't move. This particular farm design requires the mobs to be able to move.

This means that this particular farm design while resource efficient, only works with 1-3 layers, and relies on the mobs to move out of the spawning areas on their own.

There are other farms that are more efficient, since they force the spawning areas clear regularly. Like this one:

While it isn't resource efficient, it will increase the efficiency of your farm quite a lot.